# slideToggle recalculate after window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this is obvious, but I haven't been able to find the answer.

I have a hover effect using slideToggle:

```
$('.item').hover(function () {
  $(this).find('.item-top').stop().slideToggle(300);
});
```

When the browser window gets resized the toggle no longer works correctly because its content has changed height. How do I make it so this keeps working even after a window resize?

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9a208erx/) If you make the window smaller than 300px you see the text will slide open but the grey background stops early.

Comment: have you tried $(window).resize() ?

Comment: Try to add a relevant fiddle.

Comment: @ristapk How would I use $(window).resize() in this case?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Added fiddle to question

Answer (score 0):

Second way to do this is to get rid off document ready event, cause this event fires only once. Something like this in JS:

```
$('div').hover(function () {
  $(this).find('p').stop().slideToggle(300);
});
```

There is updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9a208erx/3/)